# Django select a valid choice error when populate select in the template

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I get a validate error when I create a form with an empty select field:

```
area_sp = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id':'area_select'}))
```

then I populate the select in the template using ajax:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/endpoint/load_areas/',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
      'postcode': postcode
  },
  headers: {
      'X-CSRFToken': "{{ csrf_token }}"
  },
  success: function (data) {
  var ret = JSON.parse(data.result);

  for (x in ret) {
    $("#area_select").append(new Option(x, ret[x]));
  }
  },
  error: function(data) {
     alert("error");
    }
});
```

Finally, when I submit the form I get the following error:

```
area_sp: Select a valid choice. 26835 is not one of the available choices.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've just forgotten to define the valid choices. You have to tell the `ChoiceField`, otherwise you'll get a `ValidationError`. The docs about [`ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield):

> Validates that the given value exists in the list of choices.

So just set the [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) attribute to whatever the form shall accept:

```
area_sp = forms.ChoiceField(
    widget=forms.Select(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id':'area_select'}
    ),
    choices=[(value1, repr1), (value2, repr2), ...]
)
```